# Calculating {z,w} from {x,y} given 200 samples of f(x, y) = (z,w)

Tags: numpy, math

What would be the best way to calculate `(z,w)` from a `(x,y)` given that we have 200 samples of
`f(x,y) = (z,w)`?

Answer (score 1):

You want a 2D interpolation function such as [**`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`**](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/scipyinterpolateinterp2d/)

Like in the linked example use `Z=f(x,y)` and set the interpolation type to `cubic` for smooth results.

```
w = interp2d(x, y, Z, kind='cubic')
```

In reality, it depends on what the data looks like in case there are better models to fit.